# Why is aurelia's fetch client catch error typed as any rather than Response

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-fetch-client

I'm cutting my teeth on Aurelia, aurelia-fetch client and Typescript.
I notice in typescript when I set up the catch function

```
.catch(error => //do something error)
```

`error` is defined by typescript as `any` but when I inspect it in the debugger I can see it is type `Response`

Why is the type `any` and not `Response` ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the return type of [`fetch` method of `HttpClient`](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/blob/5495e9cd6399ce6e59b62837cb4de7754fea5914/dist/aurelia-fetch-client.d.ts#L258) is `Promise<Response>`:

```
fetch(input: Request | string, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response>;
```

So the `catch` you are referring to comes from `Promise` actually. The type definition of the `catch` comes from TypeScript (`lib.d.ts`) actually:

```
/**
 * Attaches a callback for only the rejection of the Promise.
 * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
 * @returns A Promise for the completion of the callback.
 */
catch<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): Promise<T | TResult>;
```

And a generic definition with `any` as type for the `reason` is quite justified as it covers all cases.

Hope this helps.